# Variable representation

Tags: prolog

I have a term, say `a(t1,t2,t3)` which I variabilize using `numbervars/3`. Then I need to extract the variables of the term, but the variables appear as:

```
a('$VAR'(0),'$VAR'(1),'$VAR'(2))
```

The problem is that `prolog` doesn't seem to recognize these terms as variables:

```
?- term_variables(a('$VAR'(0),'$VAR'(1),'$VAR'(3)),L).
L = [].
```

Or even simpler:

```
?- var('$VAR'(0)).
false.
```

On the other hand, if I use `copy_term/2`, it sees the variables correctly, but still `term_variables/2` won't extract them:

```
?- copy_term(a('$VAR'(0),'$VAR'(1),'$VAR'(3)),Term),term_variables(Term,Vars).
Term = a(A, B, D),
Vars = [].
```

Does anyone has any idea what I am doing wrong? I'm really stuck and I can't work further in the  program I'm developing because of this.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I'm unsure about how you're using [`numbervars/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=numbervars/3), which is implemented so as to "*...unify the free variables of [a term] with a term `$VAR(N)`"*, which can't be used directly to turn the term `a(t1,t2,t3)` into `a('$VAR'(0),'$VAR'(1),'$VAR'(2))` as you suggest, unless `t1`, `t2` and `t3` are your place-holders for distinct variables.

The terms `'$VAR'(N)` that SWI's [`numbervars/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=numbervars/3) generates are indeed **terms**, and not variables (as described in the manual), so can't be treated as variables.

Note that, if you see this:

```
?- copy_term(a('$VAR'(0),'$VAR'(1),'$VAR'(3)),Term).
Term = a(A, B, D).
```

What is happening is that the line `Term = a(A, B, D).` is being written via something like [`write_term/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=write_term/2) to the console, which can be configured to portray certain terms like `'$VAR'(N)` as named variables (which can be misleading). Notice that if you try this instead:

```
?- copy_term(a('$VAR'(0),'$VAR'(1),'$VAR'(3)),Term), 
   write_term(Term, [numbervars(false)]).
a($VAR(0), $VAR(1), $VAR(3))
Term = a(A, B, D).
```

The call to [`write_term/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=write_term/2) here explicitly disables the `numbervars` option, and prints out the *true* bindings of the arguments of the `a/3` term, which are indeed  `$VAR(N)` terms. The next line printed to the console (i.e., `Term = a(A, B, D)`) is doing something akin to *enabling* the `numbervars` option instead (perhaps for readability).

If you need to 'variablize' a term, I can suggest something along these lines instead:

```
% takes a term T, a list of [Term:Variable] replacements R, and makes V:

variablize(T, R, V) :-
    member(R0:V, R),
    R0 == T, !.

variablize([T|Ts], R, [NT|NTs]) :-
    !,
    variablize(T, R, NT),
    variablize(Ts, R, NTs).

variablize(T, R, NT) :-
    compound(T), !,
    T =.. [F|As],
    variablize(As, R, NAs),
    NT =.. [F|NAs].

variablize(T, _, T).
```

Example:

```
?- variablize(a(t1,t2,t3), [t1:X, t2:Y, t3:Z], T).
T = a(X, Y, Z).
```

This assumes that you know which sub-elements (e.g., `t2`) you want replaced, and with which variables. This particular implementation could more accurately be called `replace/3`, as it will find-and-replace any sub-element occurrence in the input term (even if they are other variables!).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. What you propose does not help much, since I do not know the term I have to variabilize.  I have to construct clauses matching some syntactic bias from knowledge, then variabilize and generalize. I use  numbervars(_,N,_), where N is  0 for the first variable and increazed for each new,  then create a varbed term using the initial functors.But I need to get the vars from the variabilized term . I  resorted to a  stupid method, writting the vared term in a file, then reading it and getting the vars. Any other suggestions are really welcome.

Comment: Your `variablize` is a pretty neat piece of code. I wish I could attain this level of Prolog proficiency!

Comment: Thanks! I hope it's helpful. I've been programming Prolog professionally full-time for several years ;)